# How to insert image to DB and place in post?

Tags: php, wordpress

It seems to be a trivial task but I just can't find a sample.

Say I have uploaded the image to temporary folder on my web server.
Now I want to insert this image to DB and place it to post.

Can someone provide a short snippet?

Comment: Are you sure you want to store your images in a regular DB? What about storing them to a folder?

Comment: battal, I thought storing attachments as post is suggested for WP

Comment: all attachments being stored in a Media gallery on the disk as well

Comment: Keep in mind that in this case you will have to ask another question - how to show a picture out of database. And better put all that mess aside

Comment: Thanks Colonel.  Yeah you're right - separate question how to link image from DB in WP

Comment: So guys, you suggest keeping uploaded images as files and link directly?

Comment: sure. it's way more reliable and will save you ton of time and code.

Comment: Colonel, being PHP expert please suggest. What file naming method you would suggest. User can upload a file with same name twice and want to keep older file. What would you do? Append current time to file name?

Comment: there are many ways. you can add time as well But more clean way is to add or increment a number like windows does: new folder 01, new folder 02 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 ways to attach images to post:

1. use post-related db table with BLOB field and then perform select for images + write `image.php?image_id` which will show actual image, this will restrict you to attach only images in your cms, but you can back-up your db with all images using phpmyadmin or so...
2. use post-related db table with column for image url (and store images to some folder), in this case you don't have to deal with `image.php?image_id` - apache will take care of this and on top of that you can attach any image with url (from other sites, etc.), not only uploaded ones

post-related table would be: id_image, id_post, [image_columns]

image_columns could include image title, date&time of last modification, and some other useful stuff...

Answer (score 2):

You can store image to binary data fields (blob):

```
$handle = fopen("picture.jpg", "rb");
$img = mysql_real_escape_string(fread($handle, filesize('picture.jpg')));
fclose($handle);
$sql = "insert into pictures(id,img) values(null,'$img')";
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you didn't like here. OK, you can do it another way ;): INSERT INTO pictures SET img = '$img'

Comment: you still do not understand the very core basics of SQL syntax. mysql_real_escape_string cannot be just one option among others. it's a thing that should be done unconditionally

Comment: ok, I see, but it's just a snippet. Consider it a pseudocode. E.g. I use DB class that has escape() method - so should I put it right as it is in my projects?

Comment: It's better to post no code at all rather than buggy "pseudocode". And what's the use of base64_encode now? it will cost you 2 encoding/decoding calls and gain nothing. also there is file_get_contents() exists in PHP for nearly ten years.

Comment: ok, Col, I think you are being too strict. IMO, the purpose of us being here is to share experience, give hints etc. If we do your way, the questioner should provide the full context of the project he's asking question on, and the answerer then should implement everything correctly. I respect your experience, but I strongly believe we as a community should be more benevolent. You are among those Guru who make people afraid to ask questions not to seem stupid. I believe each of us should be learning, constantly. But, of course, that's only my opinion.

Comment: Nope, I am not being too strict. Watching **thousands** questions where authors have no idea of escaping strings, I can blame only answers like your initial one. We are here to share experience, not darn dangerous code!

Comment: Ok, let us pretend none of us ever wrote bad code. :) Still this is not an issue here. The issue is that your experience will be of more use in case you don't call everyone ignorant moron for a mistake but point to it courteously. Programming is programming, but we are not computers... Ok, sorry if I offended you in any way, I didn't mean it.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to display images stored in database :

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__image_gallery_%28blob_storage%29.xml